# AngularJS - Google Maps not displaying

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, google-maps

I don't get any erros about google maps or angular, but map is not showing. Any tips?

My code:

.cshtml file: (angular + angular-route version 1.4.5.)

```
  <script src="~/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="~/lib/gmaps/gmaps.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/lib/travelmap/travelmap.min.js"></script>
```

.html file + css file:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id="map"></div>
 </div>

#map{ height: 600px; width:800px;}
```

Important part of AngularJS:

```
$http.get("/api/trips/" + vm.tripName + "/stops")
    .then(function (response) {
        angular.copy(response.data, vm.stops);
        _showMap(vm.stops);
    });

    function _showMap(stops) {
        var mapStops = _.map(stops, function (item) {
            return {
                lat: item.latitude,
                long: item.longitude,
                info: item.name
            };
        });
        travelMap.createMap({
            stops: mapStops,
            selector: "#map",
            currentStop: 1,
            initialZoom: 3
        });
    }
```

I have tried editing .css file and I have also tried with different  google maps includes but nothing works. Has someone perhaps seen something similar and can help me?

P.S. Just noticed something, all the Stops get's added to a "Map" it has + and - button and all the dots connected, but I can't see map itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444276/angularjs-google-maps-not-displaying

Comment: is anything showing in console?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded 
 :port/api/trips/US%20Trip/stops with a status of 400 (Bad Request)